# QTextEdit vs QPlainTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtextedit, qplaintextedit

What's the difference between `QTextEdit` and `QPlainTextEdit`, why use one over the other?

I'm coding a text editor as an exercice to learn Qt5, and now I'm wondering whether to use `QTextEdit` or `QPlainTextEdit`.
So far I've only found out that you can display images in `QTextEdit`, but other than that they look somewhat identical to me.
My text editor should support some basic syntax highlighting (probably using `textChanged()` signal), but that's pretty much as far as the requirements go.

Google searches for *"QTextEdit vs QPlainTextEdit"* and *"QTextEdit compared to QPlainTextEdit"* didn't give me any decent results that would compare the two classes.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

From [QPlainTextEdit's documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qplaintextedit.html#details):

- [Introduction and Concepts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qplaintextedit.html#introduction-and-concepts):

> `QPlainTextEdit` is an advanced viewer/editor supporting plain text. It
> is optimized to handle large documents and to respond quickly to user
> input.
>
> QPlainText uses very much the same technology and concepts as
> `QTextEdit`, but is optimized for plain text handling.
>
> `QPlainTextEdit` works on paragraphs and characters. A paragraph is a
> formatted string which is word-wrapped to fit into the width of the
> widget. By default when reading plain text, one newline signifies a
> paragraph. A document consists of zero or more paragraphs. Paragraphs
> are separated by hard line breaks. Each character within a paragraph
> has its own attributes, for example, font and color.

- [Differences to QTextEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qplaintextedit.html#differences-to-qtextedit):

> `QPlainTextEdit` is a thin class, implemented by using most of the
> technology that is behind `QTextEdit` and `QTextDocument`. Its performance
> benefits over `QTextEdit` stem mostly from using a different and
> simplified text layout called `QPlainTextDocumentLayout` on the text
> document (see `QTextDocument::setDocumentLayout()`). The plain text
> document layout does not support tables nor embedded frames, and
> replaces a pixel-exact height calculation with a line-by-line
> respectively paragraph-by-paragraph scrolling approach. This makes it
> possible to handle significantly larger documents, and still resize
> the editor with line wrap enabled in real time. It also makes for a
> fast log viewer (see `setMaximumBlockCount()`).

So the difference is that `QPlainTextEdit` is optimized for handling plain text, and can be used even with very large plain text files. Also the way text is formatted is simpler.

If you plan to support only plain texts, then `QPlainTextEdit` is the right choice.

Comment: Can I still use syntax highlighting for `QPlainTextEdit` ?

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen [Yes](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qplaintextedit.html#syntax-highlighting).