# Qt Command Log using QListWidget

Tags: c++, c++11, qt5, qlistwidget, qcheckbox

I am trying to build a command log on a user interface. Meaning, when the user click a button, check a box, upload some images etc, basically every time the user interacts with the user interface the action is recorded inside a `QListWidget` Command Log shown below. Basically this is how the ui looks as soon as the user run it:

[image: start]

And this is what I am try to achieve everytime the user interacts with the ui:

[image: command_log]

Below snippets of code from the constructor:

**mainwindow.h**

```
private:
    QListWidget *mNewTextSQLLog;
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mDockWidget_A = new QDockWidget(QLatin1String("Command Log"));
    mDockWidget_A->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding,QSizePolicy::Expanding);
    mDockWidget_A->setMinimumHeight(30);
    // Adding object to the DockWidget
    mNewText = new QListWidget;
    mNewText->setStyleSheet("background-color: light grey;");
    mNewText->setMinimumHeight(50);
    mNewText->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
    mDockWidget_A->setWidget(mNewText);
    addDockWidget(Qt::BottomDockWidgetArea, mDockWidget_A);
    resizeDocks({mDockWidget_A}, {200}, Qt::Horizontal);
}
```

And then some command of the ui, for example here is when the user upload images using a `QPushButton` and images are also shown on a `QLabel`:

```
void MainWindow::imageOriginlUploadB()
{
    dir_Original_B = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Choose an image directory to load"),
                                                     filesListRight, QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);
    if(dir_Original_B.length() > 0){
        QImage image;
        QDir dirBObj(dir_Original_B);
        QStringList filesListRight = dirBObj.entryList(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::System | QDir::Hidden  | QDir::AllDirs | QDir::Files, QDir::DirsFirst);
        ui->labelOrigImageB->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image.scaled(125,125,Qt::KeepAspectRatio,Qt::SmoothTransformation)));
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < filesListRight.size() ; i++ )
        {
            ui->listWidgetOriginalImgB->addItem(filesListRight.at(i));
        }
        ui->listWidgetOriginalImgB->update();
        ui->labelOrigImageB->show();
    }
}


void MainWindow::on_originalmgB_clicked()
{
    imageOriginlUploadB();
}
```

or here is resizing the `QGraphicsView` using a `QPushButton`:

```
void MainWindow::on_fitViewBtn_clicked()
{
    ui->graphicsViewLX->fitInView(mLeftScene->sceneRect(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
    ui->graphicsViewRX->fitInView(mRightScene->sceneRect(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
}
```

And this is the activation of a `QCheckBox`:

```
void MainWindow::on_checkBoxScreen_A_toggled(bool checked)
{
    if(ui->checkBoxScreen_A->isEnabled()) {
        if(checked)
        {
            ui->checkBoxScreen_A->setText("Active");
            ui->saveToFile_A->setEnabled(true);
            ui->saveToFile_A->setStyleSheet("QPushButton{ background-color: green }");
        }
        else {
            ui->checkBoxScreen_A->setText("Inactive");
            ui->saveToFile_A->setEnabled(false);
            ui->saveToFile_A->setStyleSheet("QPushButton{ background-color: grey }");
        }
    }
}
```

How to achieve that? 
Thank you very much for pointing in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `QListWidget` isn't quite the right widget to use for a Command Log -- you probably want to use either a [QPlainTextEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html) or a [QTextEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html) instead.  (The main [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466046/qtextedit-vs-qplaintextedit) between the two is that QPlainTextEdit is optimized for displaying large amounts of text, at the expense of not supporting some of the fancier text-formatting features provided by QTextEdit)

Once you've created one of those two widgets, adding text to the bottom of log is just a matter of calling [appendPlainText()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#appendPlainText) (or [append()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#append)) on the widget each time you want to add another line of log-text.

Unless you want to allow the user to edit the text in the Command Log, calling `setReadOnly(true)` on the widget is also a good idea.

(If you also want the log-view to automatically scroll to the bottom so that the newly-added text will be visible, you can also call `myCommandLogWidget->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(myCommandLogWidget->verticalScrollBar()->maximum());` after adding the text)

Comment: @ Jeremy Friesner, thank you for the very detailed answer. On the command log I am planning to give the user positive or negative feedback of the action take using some icons for visual help [like this](https://i.imgur.com/fSBWAfM.png). In my design I Am planning to help the user with at least 7/10 icons.

Comment: But also at the same time I am try to think about speed. I mean the Command Log should to take a long time when the user decides to scroll up and down, especially when there are icons.

Comment: Thanks also [for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466046/qtextedit-vs-qplaintextedit). It seems that the best choice for this project would be to use a `QTextEdit`. Thank you very much for the clarification :)

Comment: Note that either of the two widgets supports Unicode, so if the icons you need are available as Unicode characters, you can use either one.  (see http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html for examples of some of the icons that are available in Unicode )